# Problems to post data of input radio type to specific URL using WebClient

Tags: .net, vb.net, post, webclient

I need to use "HTTP Post" with WebClient to post some data to a specific URL. 
I have some problems to pass a value to input type "Radio".

Partial web code:

```
<li class='cua_cols'>NIF a seleccionar<br />
<big><strong>A********</strong></big>
</li>
<li><label for='wNif'><input type='hidden' id='wNif' name='wNif'  value='A********' /></label></li>
<li class='dos_cols'>
<label for='TIPONIF0'>
que actúa como
<br />
</label>
<b>Operador </b><input type='radio' id='TIPONIF0'  name='TIPONIF' value='OP' checked = 'checked'  />
<b>Autorizado </b><input type='radio' id='TIPONIF1'  name='TIPONIF' value='AU'  />
</li>
<li class='ancho_99'>&nbsp;</li><li class='cua_cols'>
<label for='wNifAut'>
NIF relacionado=
<br />
<input type='text' name='wNifAut' id='wNifAut' value='B********' maxlength='17' size='19'   onkeypress='javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13)  return false; ' onclick='' />
</label></li>
<li class='cua_cols'>
<label for='TIPONIF_SOL0'>
 que actúa como
<br />
</label>
<b>Operador </b><input type='radio' id='TIPONIF_SOL0'  name='TIPONIF_SOL' value='OP'  />
<b>Autorizado </b><input type='radio' id='TIPONIF_SOL1'  name='TIPONIF_SOL' value='AU' checked = 'checked'  />
</li>
```

In a first time the next code worked correctly but today only asign the wNifAut value.

```
Dim requestData As New NameValueCollection()
requestData.Add("wNifAut", mnoCIF)
requestData.Add("TIPONIF1", "true")
requestData.Add("TIPONIF_SOL0", "true")
requestData.Add("Buscar", "Click")           

Dim request As Byte() = myWebClient.UploadValues(msStrURL, "POST", requestData)
msHTMLString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

The source code of the page contains this too:

```
  <label for="VEZ"><input name="VEZ" id="VEZ" type="hidden" value=""></label>

<div class="AEAT_bloque_botones">
<input name="Buscar" class="AEAT_boton" accesskey="A" onkeypress='javascript:enviarDatos("BUSCAR1");' onclick='javascript:enviarDatos("BUSCAR1");' type="button" value="Buscar">
<input name="Limpiar" class="AEAT_boton" accesskey="D" onkeypress='javascript:resetear(getVarDom("Query"));' onclick='javascript:resetear(getVarDom("Query"));' type="button" value="Limpiar">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function enviarDatos(opcion) { getVarDom("Query").VEZ.value=opcion;  
  getVarDom("Query").submit(); }
</script>
```

I changed some lines in my code:

```
  Dim requestData As New NameValueCollection()
            requestData.Add("wNif", mnoCIFComp)
            requestData.Add("wNifAut", mnoCIF)
            requestData.Add("TIPONIF", "AU")
            requestData.Add("TIPONIF_SOL", "OP")
            requestData.Add("VEZ", "BUSCAR1")

  Dim request As Byte() = myWebClient.UploadValues(msStrURL, "POST", requestData)
   msHTMLString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(request)
```

IMPORTANT CHANGES

```
1) I indicated the input radio values with pair (name - value) instead of (id - 'true')
2) I assigned the value "BUSCAR1" to the hidden label, to simulated the JavaScript function.
3) In this case I had to assign the company cif.
```